# cin in C++ trying to assign string values to an int variable?

Tags: c++

I'm working through Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming - Principles and Practice Using C++ and came to the following example:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
    /* Name and Age input */
    cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
    string first_name = "???";
    int age = -1.0;
    cin >> first_name >> age;
    cout << "Hello," << first_name << "(age " << (age * 12) << " months)\n";
    return 0;
 }
```

If you run the program and input Carlos 22, it will correctly output `Hello, Carlos (age 22)`. However, if you put in 22 Carlos, he says that the output should be `Hello, 22 (age -1)` because since "Carlos isn't an integer... it will not be read". However, when I run it, it returns `Hello, 22 (age 0)` which seems like it's assigning a garbage value to it. I'm curious as to why this is happening, as the book implies that unless you input an integer, it won't try to assign anything to the `age` variable. I ran the code with breakpoints and confirmed the value of `age` changes from -1 to 0 once the non-integer input has been entered.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this an oddity due to the fact I'm building it through Xcode and whatever compiler comes included with that?

Comment: This is an `undefined behaviour` that you are getting. In such cases the output can be anything

Comment: C++11 onwards will set scalar types to 0 when extraction fails, prior to C++11 the value was left untouched.

Comment: @user657267, Ah, thanks for that. I was confused because it was the updated edition of the book for C++11, but after reading your comment, I looked up the errata and sure enough, there was a note about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you follow the trail of calls from the call

```
cin >> age;
```

you end up with a call to [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol). The return value of `strtol` is:

> - If no conversion can be performed, ​0​ is returned.

Check the status of `cin` after the calls to make sure that all the extractions were successful.

```
cin >> first_name >> age;
if ( cin )
{
   // Extraction was successful.
   // Use the data.
}
else
{
   // Extraction was not successful.
   // Deal with the error.
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I just looked up the errata for the book and found this:

"This is not really an errata, but some implementations zero out an int when >> fails. Eventually all will, but until C++11 none did. So, you get 0 or -1 depending on the vintage of your implementation."

So like you pointed out, it's implementing the standards as it should. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan, it's unfortunate that books, even by the father of the language, become obsolete not before too long.